# Does a Dwarven Thrower automatically return to the thrower's hands?

Tags: dnd-4e

[Dwarven Thrower](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=782):

> Property
>
> This weapon can be used as a heavy thrown weapon with a range of 6/12.

Does the fact that it "can be used as" indicate that it *is* a heavy thrown weapon for purposes of magical weapons returning to the user?

Citations would be nice.

Comment: This question asked because of annoying precedent in the game where I'm planning on using a dwarven thrower as a central component of a scout with throw & stab. I'm looking for an argumentative chain of citations to show that dwarven throwers do indeed return.

Comment: I'm 98% certain it does count because of the FAQ entry not specifying that the weapon's primary purpose has to be a thrown weapon...but I have no hard citations to that other than Iain's answer.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton you must play in one of the most rules lawyerly groups :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off of @SevenSidedDie's comment on @IainAnderson's answer:

Magic Thrown Weapons return to the thrower after an attack.

If we assume that after some attack with dwarven thrower, that it does not return to the thrower after the attack, then it must not have been a thrown weapon.

Since the dwarven thrower was thrown, then it's can't not be a thrown weapon, and so it returns.

Answer (score 6):

Question 13 of the DnD Insider FAQ:
13. I am using a magical thrown weapon as part of an area of effect power.  If I am attacking multiple enemies within that area, do I need multiple weapons, or will one suffice?

One is enough in this case.  **Magical thrown weapons return to you after each attack**, so you’ll be able to use it against each enemy as part of using your power.

Perhaps I don't understand your question, but all magical thrown weapons return to the thrower. *I would assume any non-missile-weapon that has a range attached to it would count as a magical thrown weapon.*

Comment: Yes. However, the base weapon is *not* a thrown weapon. The question is: does "can be used as" turn it into a thrown weapon? (This is a stupidly pedantic question, I know, but I've asserted the same thing you have.)

Comment: @Brian First assume it doesn't work. Then it *cannot* be used "as a thrown weapon". Since that's a contradiction, the assumption is wrong.

Comment: Cool. That's really good logic, actually. Disproving the contrapositive, right
?

Comment: The question is whether or not the "heavy thrown" keyword is added to the weapon's property list. I argue it is, though I'm working on formulating why

Comment: @SevenSidedDie should your comment be an answer?

Comment: @Simon Nah, it was more in response to Brian's comment. I don't consider myself an expert when it comes to 4e, anyway, so I try not to give half-informed answers. Sometimes I feel a comment can be helpful, is all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because dwarven throwers have existed in previous editions, and there they specifically gain the returning special ability. It's the whole point of their iconic deal.